# Teamcity VCS Triggers On Every Commit When Branches Are Merged

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a Teamcity build configuration which needs to run per every commit or merge (and per committer) on my develop branch.
Whenever a branch is merged into develop a build build is triggered per every past commit to the merged branch.
This behavior is causing Trouble and i need a way to tell TC to trigger only one build per commit.

Any ideas?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do exactly what you want.
Squashing commits into single one before merging might be used as a possible workaround.

Also, it is a good idea to file a bug/request in the [TeamCity issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW).